# How to continue to command by PHP if error occurs in first command

Tags: php, command, system, xvfb

I want to execute several commands by PHP,

```
//DISPLAY setting
$command1 = 'export DISPLAY=:1';    
$last_line1 = system($command , $rtn);

//use Xvfb
$command2 = 'Xvfb :1 -screen 0 '.$width.'x'.$height.'x24 &';
$last_line2 = system($command , $rtn);

//open firefox
$command3 = 'firefox -display :1 -width '.$width.' -height '.$height.' -P "webshot" &';
$last_line3 = system($command , $rtn);

//open URL
$command4 = 'firefox -display :1 -remote "openurl('http://www.google.com')" &';
$last_line4 = system($command , $rtn);
```

command3 occurs some errors ,but they can ignore.
I want to continue to execute command4,but command3 occurs some errors,so it cannot be executed.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Try to use `popen` or `proc_open` instead

Comment: What kind of error? It should be continuing, a failed `system` call does not typically end execution.

Comment: @Alon `system` does not throw Exceptions.

Comment: @Alon Virtually *no* PHP *function* throws Exceptions. The newer OOP oriented classes often do, and if so it's clearly documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `error_reporting(0)` at the top of the page.. Though it s not a good programming practice, it s the solution for ur problem

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use a try catch in order to catch exception related to your system command